# iOS Project Pods have conflicting folder name

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So i'm using these two pods in my project:

`pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'MSOutlook-SDK-iOS'`

To my delight, they both have dependencies that use a `Core.h` file. I believe i am running into issues that cause a `File Not Found` for one of the pods because it is looking for a file in the wrong header!

I guess I can make the import explicit, aka changing:

`core.h/NSArray+Utils.h`

to

`orc/core.h/NSArray+Utils.h`

But I don't want to do that bc of two reasons:

1. These pods get updated from time to time, and might introduce new files/overwrite existing changes
2. There are about 350 files I need to do that to.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Possibly some renaming or settings change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This purported error has claimed to been fixed in Cocoapods v1.0 and above.

From [github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5131#issuecomment-207600864):

**"This ought to be fixed in CocoaPods 1.0 if you use bracket imports."**